# What is the syntax for the iconName modifier in an Apex InvocableMethod?

Tags: apex, invocable-method

The [InvocableMethod docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) say this about the `iconName` modifier:

> The name of the icon to use as a custom icon for the action in the Flow Builder canvas. You can specify an SVG file that you uploaded as a static resource or a Salesforce Lightning Design System standard icon.

But there are no examples of its use. I checked a few GitHub repos and didn't find any examples there, either. I tried:

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Get Territory Member'
                 description='Finds the contractor assigned to a Location' 
                 iconName='action:map')
```

But get the error `Annotation property, the format of iconName on InvocableMethod is invalid, please check if the iconName has the correct formats` when saving. I tried other SLDS icon collections & names, to no avail. I'm primarily interested in the syntax for SLDS icons, but if someone knows the static resource syntax also, that'd be great.

Comment: Never tried it but try this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_build_extend_apex_type.htm&type=5

Comment: Also make sure class api is 55 and above.

Comment: Nagendra's comment has the proper syntax, 'slds:standard:whatever'. The InvocableMethod documentation references 'Salesforce Lightning Design System standard icon', and I could only get standard icons to display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `iconName` property has to follow the format `ns:cateogry:name`. If using the Salesforce Lightning Design System (SLDS) with a standard icon, for example, the string should be `'slds:standard:work_plan_template_entry'`.

Comment: Hi Renato, thanks it works, but where did you get the info, can't find it...

Comment: It is described in the "Automate Your Business Processes" document, under Flow Builder > Build > Extend Toolbox > Apex > Apex-Defined Data Type > Add a Custom Icon to an Apex-Defined Action. Here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_build_extend_apex_type_add_a_custom_icon.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you for the link, that's a deep path :) !